# Robolectric, create Thread without looper

Tags: android, multithreading, robolectric

I'm trying to create Thread in robolectric without looper.
I need to test that my code with Handler instantiation, that should fail.

I'm expecting "java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()", but code works fine.

Is this possible in robolectric to create Thread without looper?
I also tried to use this shadow:

```
@Implements(value = Looper.class, callThroughByDefault = true)
public static class EmptyLooper extends ShadowLooper {

    public static Looper myLooper() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest=Config.NONE, shadows={MyTest.EmptyLooper.class})
public class MyTest {
    @Implements(value = Looper.class)
    public static class EmptyLooper extends ShadowLooper {
       @Implementation
       public static synchronized Looper myLooper() {
           if (Thread.currentThread() != getMainLooper().getThread()) return null;
           else return ShadowLooper.myLooper();
       }
   }
}
```